# Template class with template method specialized for itself

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Lets say I have template class with template function. Example:

```
template<typename T>
class example
{
    T some_member;

    template<typename X>
    example& foo(X& val)
    {
        /* general stuff */
        return *this;
    }

    // rest of class
};
```

What I'm failing to achieve is to make specialization for this method which takes as argument object of type example < T > (same type as caller's).
Little example to show how it suppose to work:

```
example<int> exampleObj;
example<int> sameTypeObj;
int diffrentType1;
example<double> diffrentType2;

exampleObj.foo(diffrentType1); // general template used
exampleObj.foo(diffrentType2); // general template used
exampleObj.foo(sameTypeObj); // specialization used
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overload, but you cannot specialize, since there is no partial template function specialization.

```
example& foo(example&)
{
}
```

Comment: correct, that's the better approach, but it wouldn't be a *partial* specialization as there's only one parameter ... ?

Comment: @davidhigh Yes it would : specializing for `example<T>` still needs parameterizing `T`.

Comment: i'll mark this as answer because it works as I want. but i'm not sure how. How compiler determines which foo should be used? and if such overloading is ok then i can't see the point of template specializations.